# WPF I cannot access a textblock in my style

Tags: c#, wpf

I make a radiobutton style and I called it RadioButtonStyle but in my code behind, when I write the name of my radiobutton Q1A  and trying Q1A.RadioContentTxt it does not come up.

[image]

see.
here is my Style : `

```html
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SpeedReadingControl">
    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Static.Border" Color="#FFE4F0FF"/>
    <Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFF3F9FF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF5593FF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFD9ECFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButton.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="OncheckSB">
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="RadioContentTxt">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFE4F0FF"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="radioButtonBorder">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="#FF0075FF"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RowSpan)" Storyboard.TargetName="radioButtonBorder">
                                <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="2"/>
                            </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" Height="14"  SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="radioButtonBorder"  BorderBrush="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="White" CornerRadius="100" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1,1,2,1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <Grid x:Name="markGrid" Margin="4" >
                                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                                    <Path  x:Name="CheckMarkIcon" Canvas.Left="-2" StrokeThickness="2"  Stretch="Fill" Stroke="White" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" Data="M427 391.5L429.5 394L435 389"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="optionMark" Fill="White" MinWidth="6" MinHeight="6" Opacity="0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="RadioContentTxt" Grid.Column="1"  Foreground="#33454B57" Margin="3,1,667.25,4562" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=""  Background="Transparent"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OncheckSB_BeginStoryboard"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OncheckSB_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OncheckSB}"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-1,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.Disabled.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.Pressed.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource RadioButton.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="0.56"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I make it using Blend.

How do I set my RadioContentTxt.Text from the code behind?
I try doing    Q1A.Content
but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the `TextBlock` in the template to the `Content` property of the control:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="RadioContentTxt" Grid.Column="1"  Foreground="#33454B57" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
           Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"  Background="Transparent"/>
```

...and set the `Content` property:

```
Q1A.Content = "...";
```

You cannot directly access an element in the template using a property of the control.